# There is no assembly when adding reference to my .NETStandard 2.0 Project in VS2017 version15.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a project in .NETStandard 2.0 . When I'm trying to use any assemblies such as ConfigurationManager in System.Configuration, I cannot find it because reference manager says: No Framework Assemblies were found on the machine.
What should I do?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: In "Dependencies" when I click "add reference" it says: "No Framework Assemblies were found on the machine"

Comment: have you try to add them? hint: [there is a nuget package for this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/)

Comment: Yes.That worked. I did not know I could get it from NuGet. Thanks...